# How to make a button in parallelogram shape in android?

Tags: android, xml, button

I have looked through the page below about how to make a triangular button. Now I would like to create a button of parallelogram shape, I tried changing the fromDegree/toDegree attributes and pivotX/pivotY attributes, yet they didn't give me satisfactory result. What should I do?

https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/

Comment: 9patch? Will that work?

Comment: You can do that by Custom Views and draw your own button using Canvas.

Use a transparent background and draw a paralleogram. On that view u just use a clicklistener.

Here is a link: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: did you get solved or not?i stuck in same